# Intervention image multiple image upload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, image-upload

in blade

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" id="" required class="form-control" multiple accept="image/*">
```

in controller

```
public function addReviewPost(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('image');

    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required',
        'image.*' => ' max:2048 | dimensions:max_width=2200',
    ]);

    if (request()->hasFile('image')) {
        $counter = count($image);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {

            $image = Image::make($image[$i]);
            $image->resize(null, 627, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $image->save(public_path('../../img/testimonial/' . time() . '.png'));
        }
    }

}
```

it shows error

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Cannot use object of type Intervention\Image\Image as array
```

can anyone please help me how can I upload multi file using intervention image package?

Comment: `dd($request->all())` and see the type of image

Comment: 0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#291 ▼
      -test: false
      -originalName: "93649267_10221642080937792_4082659911438172160_n.jpg"
      -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
      -error: 0
      #hashName: null
      path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
      filename: "php19F3.tmp"
      basename: "php19F3.tmp"
      pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php19F3.tmp"
      extension: "tmp"
      realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\php19F3.tmp"
      type: "file"
      writable: true
      readable: true
      executable: false
      file: true
      dir: false
 link: false
 linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\php19F3.tmp"
 }

Comment: here is the output of image array

Comment: It shows only one image.

Comment: no. It has 2 image in array. i copied one of them to give you

Comment: array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "F5emz90fj3wnvnZPhJwneRI2HySCEAinBWl8OSHL"
  "title" => "SUPER SILVER"
  "date" => "2020-03-31"
  "venue" => "Tongi"
  "photographer" => "Anik"
  "review" => "ssrdhfgj"
  "image" => array:2 [▼
    0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#291 ▶}
    1 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#294 ▶}
  ]
]

Comment: this is the full array of request

Comment: `$image = $request->image;` then `dd($image)`

Comment: Can You please elaborate what do You want to know? My question was how to upload multiple file using intervention package. this function already works in single upload. but not in multiple because of array. image type is jpeg.. now i think you understand my problem

Comment: Is your code failing in the validation or after?

Comment: I used intervention/Image package to resize my photo.  see my controller function
`$image = Image::make($image[$i]);` in this line it throws error that `Cannot use object of type Intervention\Image\Image as array` thats the problem. if i can't use array then how can I upload multiple files?

Comment: okay, please provide the output of then `dd($request->image)` in your question

Comment: Does your form has `method="post"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"`???

Comment: array:2 [▼
  0 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#291 ▶}
  1 => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#294 ▶}
]

Comment: Yes I have akshay

Comment: full output can't be written in this comment box

Comment: please add it to your question, not in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
   public function addReviewPost(Request $request)
    {
     if (request()->hasFile('image')) {
        $images = $request->file('image');
        foreach ($images as $key => $file) { 
            $image = Image::make($request->file($file));
            $image->resize(null, 627, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $image->save(public_path('../../img/testimonial/' . time() . '.png'));
        }
    }
    }
```

Let me know If you get any errors.

Don't forget to mark it answer if works

Hope it helps you

Thank you

Comment: I already solved the problem using for loop. thanks for your answer. 
it also worked. 
thank you...

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple accept="image/*">
```

Controller

```
foreach ($request->images as $key=>$image) {
                $iimage = Image::make($image)
                                ->resize(350, 150)
                                ->encode('jpg');

            Storage::disk('local')->put('public/gallery_images/' . $image->hashName(), (string)$iimage, 'public');
            $request_data['image']    = 'gallery_images/'. $image->hashName();
            $request_data['owner_id'] = auth()->guard('owner')->user()->id;

            Gallery::create($request_data);
        
        }//end of foreach
```